# How to replace content using ng-content in angular

Tags: angular, primeng

In order to implement row expansion using PrimeNG, I have two components a parent and a child. I want to replace some code in the parent component by adding just `ng-content` in the child but I'm not getting it. How do I fix that ?

I tried to use `ng-content` and then replace it with some code in the parent component.

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" id="idexpendable" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <ng-content select="expandableContent">
    </ng-content>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

and in my parent component :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="expandable" ngProjectAs="expandableContent">
  <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length + 1" id="exp">
    <div class="ui-g ui-fluid " style="font-size:16px;padding:20px">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9" style="margin-left:30%">
        <div class="ui-g">
          <div class="ui-g-12">
            <b>Profession:</b> {{rowData?.job}}
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12">
            <b>Marié(e):</b> {{rowData?.married}}
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12">
            <b>Date d'anniversaire:</b> {{rowData?.birthDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12">
            <b>Langue:</b> {{rowData?.language}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

I'm expecting to get the same behaviour as in PrimeNG row expansion but it's not working (but if i directly put the whole code without `ng-content` it works)

Comment: ```ng-content``` is use for adding content to your custom generated component.
here is [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content) for example.

Comment: The `ng-container` needs to be wrapped by the component that uses `ng-content`. What is the name of the component where the templated is meant to be injected?